# How to know which layout qualifier to use?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best way to find the best layout qualifiers for a specific Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this kind of application:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sturnus.screeninfo
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lt.andro.screensize

To retrieve density, screen size, ...

Answer (score 4):

There are no resource qualifiers that are device-specific. For example, you can't specify `layout-neuxs-5`.

This is because you rarely want to change a layout for one specific device when there are likely dozens of other similar devices that need a similar layout (or other set of resources).

The first step then is identifying what exactly defines the type of device that needs a different resource. You can provide different resources of any type (layout, drawable, string, etc.) for any sort of qualifier you can imagine- language, screen orientation, screen size, screen density, and more.

While you didn't provide any specifics, I'm going to assume that you are looking to provide different layouts for differently sized screens. For this, you generally want to use the smallest-width qualifier (e.g. `layout-sw320dp`, `layout-sw720dp`).

If that's the case, then the real question you are asking is likely more along the lines of "how do I know what size screen a device has?" To calculate that, you need to know two things:

- The device's density class (mdpi, xhdpi, etc., which you can calculate based on the physical screen size and resolution)
- The device's *resolution*

Let's look at the Nexus 5. It is and xxhdpi device and its resolution is 1080 x 1920 pixels. xxhdpi is a 3x scale, and the smallest dimension is 1080, thus 1080 divided by 3 = 360dp. The smallest width of a Nexus 5 is 360dp.

Thus to provide resources that are at least the approximate size of a Nexus 5, you would put those resources in a folder with the `-sw360dp` qualifier.

Here are some common sizes suggested by the documentation:

> - 320, for devices with screen configurations such as:
>
>   - 240x320 ldpi (QVGA handset)
>   - 320x480 mdpi (handset)
>   - 480x800 hdpi (high-density handset)
> - 480, for screens such as 480x800 mdpi (tablet/handset).
> - 600, for screens such as 600x1024 mdpi (7" tablet).
> - 720, for screens such as 720x1280 mdpi (10" tablet).

Comment: While this is - in theory - a nice explanation, it's way more complicated in the real world: e.g. the Nexus 4 and the Nexus 5X both use the sw320dp ressources which results in either one of the two layouts beeing not usable. Only way to be certain, that your app is displayed properly is by using the swXXX AND the mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi qualifier in combination.